# Abs exercises for abs with no contact between back and surface

Tags: exercise, abdominals, home-exercise

I made lots of abs exercises in order to strengthen my abs and make it 6 packs. Unfortunately, I injured my back while doing the exercises. I would to know if there are any exercises that can be done to achieve my goal at this period without a contact between my back and surface (floor). In addition, I have no equipment (except from dumb bells and kettle bell) and I do them at home.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you injure your back and which part of your back?

There are quite a few you can do that have no back contact with the floor, such as:

- planks (many variations),
- mountain climbers,
- L-sits, L-sit leg raises/knee raises
- if your dumbbells are round and can roll, definitely use them for abwheel roll-outs, amazing exercise
- if you have something to hang from, hanging knee/leg raises, windshield wipers, front/back levers

What you could or should do will really depend on the sort of injury you have though. ALso remember to balance out your muscles, if you're strengthening your abs also work on your lower back and obliques/sides. And don't just do upper abs (crunches), do lower abs too (leg raises, etc).